# Check if uint8_t array is empty

Tags: arduino, uint8t

If I declare the following (which hold a HEX like {0x7E, 0x00, ...}):

```
uint8_t response[size];
```

And I print with:

```
void printHex(uint8_t* hex) {

  for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(hex)/sizeof(hex[0]); i++) {
    if(hex[i] < 16) {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(hex[i], HEX);
  }

}
```

It prints this which I don't know from where it came:

```
0088FE3FF0FBFE3FA0382040A0ECFE3FAE10204001000000DCEBFE3FC033204018000000BC981800
```

Even though I've not initilized the variable with any value.
The problem is that I cannot tell whether the variable has ben initilized with values or not. How to accomplish this? And why it prints the above without initilizing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't determine the size of a pointer array in C. You have to pass in the array length in, unless it is statically allocated. However that is not the case with anything where you pass in a pointer.